# Advice on how to organise the levels in a game

Tags: platformer, levels, spritekit, swift

I'm thinking of building a 2D platformer game similar to Super Mario Bros, but I'm in the planning process and realised I don't really have a good way of storing information about each level – where should the enemies be placed, where do they walk, what happens if the player enters an area etc.

At first I thought I could make one scene per level, but with 40 to 50 levels I had a feeling that it would get messy pretty quickly. A friend of mine recommended making an array or dictionary containing every single wall, enemy and item a level contained. At first glance this too seemed like a good idea, but since every level is quite different it seems like building an effective system for detecting what the player is doing and where (s)he is at any given time is a really big challenge. This is because I would have to check which level the player is playing in addition to all the other logic, and then maybe it'll get messy anyways?

And so i figured out I maybe just should go with my first idea: It seems like making a separate file and class for each level will make it easier to tailor everything so that the game runs smooth and doesn't encounter issues at runtime. The question is whether this would slow down the loading process a lot, or if there are other issues using this method.

Since this is my first large project though, I'm not too sure what is the best thing to do for a 2D game where each level features different objects, enemies, items, audio etc. What is your advice? Thank you for your time.

Btw., I'm programming this in Swift and use SpriteKit.

Comment: What framework/engine are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to tell you. I'm using Swift with SpriteKit

Comment: Both solutions sound like they'd work. The scene option sounds like you could get up and running faster, and test if it actually gives you problems in practice, rather than going off of feelings or hearsay from Internet strangers.

Comment: I see. If you guys (who actually have some experience) say there's no problem with neither of them, I'll just go with the multiple class/scene solution. The reason why I was skeptical is because I don't know how this will affect performance, but it'll probably be okay then.